# Create a trial period for ruby on rails web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications

can anyone tell me the best way to implement a 30 trial period for a ruby on rails web app, much like the way [Basecamp from 37signals](https://signup.37signals.com/basecamp/Plus/signup/new?source=37signals%20home&__utma=1.679611873.1308228040.1308228040.1308228040.1&__utmb=1.7.10.1308228039&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1308228040.1.1.utmcsr=%28direct%29%7Cutmccn=%28direct%29%7Cutmcmd=%28none%29&__utmv=-&__utmk=234381470) does?

At the moment I have a user signin up page which then gives a user access to a dashboard displaying current information on their products/pricing etc.

I would like users to be able to signup and have full app functionality which then expires after 30 days.

Thanks

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the answers. In doing a bit of research I stumbled upon [link](http://railskits.com/saas/) which contained everything that I needed. I was able to import the SaaS plugin into my existing app and get a trial period and payment system (much like 37signals) up and running pretty quickly after some tweaking.

Comment: Could you please share the link that you found and used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Creating Rails application for x days trial period is pretty much easy.

You want to implement a 30 days trial period for your users then follow:

step 1: create these methods in application_controller.rb like

```
# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 # make expire_on method available for all the controllers
 helper :all
 helper :remaining_days


 # find the remaining trial days for this user
 def remaining_days
  ((current_user.created_at + 30.days).to_date - Date.today).round
 end

 def trial_expired?
  # find current_user who is login. If you are using devise simply current_user will works
  # now that you have remaining_days, check whether trial period is already completed
  if remaining_days <= 0
     redirect_to expires_path
  end
 end
end
```

Step 2: Display the Remaining Trial Days in application.html.erb

```
# application.html.erb
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <span style="color:red"> Your trial period will expire on <%= remaining_days %></span>  Days. Suscribe
  </body>
 </html>
```

step 3: in every controller write

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
 before_filter trial_expired?
end
```

so that if trial is already expired it will not give access to your page, but redirect user back to error message page.

Now create one **expires controller** and do all the required function there. In expires > index page display some error message like "Your trial period is completed please subscribe................." whatever you like.

This works for me.

Comment: Following this pattern, but keep getting "undefined method trial_expired?" when added to the UsersController. Any ideas why the users controller wouldn't recognize the trial_expired? method?

Comment: Hi @przbadu, thanks for your answer, a question i had was, there is no real need to round the value in `remaining_days` method, correct? can't think of a case where the difference between two `to_dates` would be float. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Simply store the date when the user account was created, along with a boolean flag whether or not the account has been paid.

Or use a date field in which you set the last day the user has the access to the full functionality (and on registering you set this date to be 30 days from registration).

In any case, read the data upon logging in and display different content based on it.

That would be my solution; but I suppose there might be something better and easier.

**Edit** I generally agree with what @Roland said in his answer. The boolean flag can be replaced with an information about the level of the account, however for that I would use an integer (0 meaning trial, 1 basic, 2 pro, etc.) over a string tag.

You can also automatically do something to accounts that have not been paid at a given day by scheduling a rake task in cron. By *do something to* I mean things like: invalidate, delete, change level to basic, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The why I'd approach it is to set a `trial_started_at` field for the user, and check this every time the user logs in, unless they've purchased.

Answer (score 0):

What Sorrow and Ant said, and but instead of a boolean use a tag for users: Trial, Basic, Pro etc.

Answer (score 0):

As Sorrow suggests:

> Use a 'date field in which you set the last day the user has the access to the full functionality >(and on registering you set this date to be 30 days from registration).

I only repost to highlight that this is the better option rather than storing when the trial begins, the code for checking the former is: `trial_expiry > Time.now`, whereas the code to check the trial started date would have to be more convoluted, and makes it difficult to cater for different length trials.

You can clear the expiry date when they purchase an account, no need to check a seperate field. Some kind of user level is still a good idea, but not necessary to the trial system.